# Need of Intermediate Assembly in ASP.NET Compilation Structure

Tags: asp.net, assembly, compilation

while asp.net compilation, code is converted in IL Assembly and then in native code.
Why we need IL assembly state? 
why we cannot convert high level language code to machine code? i think it will enhance time and speed?

Comment: IL Assembly instructions are in Bytecode. It does not have any target platform or CPU. You can run it in any platform it supports (for example Microsoft .Net runtime , Mono Platform). During runtime, Bytecode will be converted to a Native code which is compatible with the taget CPU. If you convert it to Native Code directly, you will have to create different executables to different platforms (For example : One for Mono and another one for Microsoft .Net)

Comment: @chathuranga thanks, you explained very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to compile to machine code straight away, but since .Net is focusing on `portability`, it is a good trade-off to compile to `IL` instead of machine code. Every platform (Win7, Win 2008 Server, Win 10 etc etc) then have specific `JIT-compilers` that handle compilation under runtime to platform specific code. Otherwise you had to compile your .Net code for the specific platform you are supposed to host your application. (For example on for your dev machine and another for your server.)

Also, since JIT-compilation is done at `runtime`, it can make optimizations depending on data that a pre-compiled version cannot. This make the JIT-compiled code sometimes faster.

By default JIT-compiled code are cached in memory and reused, so it only have to compile certain code once.

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation) is a good article going trough the pros and cons with JIT vs Native.